# Spring Boot - Why Use a Domain Model with JDBC Templates?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm figuring out my simple MySQL schema implementation for my front end and made the decision to use JDBC Templates since I love doing as much "thinking" as I can directly in SQL, however I'm seeing that most JDBC Template implementations wind up creating their own object-entity model anyway (similar to JPA/Hibernate).

I simply want to output my tables on my front end and be able to insert/update/delete. Is their no way to avoid mapping my entities to objects, no matter which implementation I choose? Although my model is simple, I have 15+ tables and mapping them all to objects seems a bit redundant if all I want to do is display tables in HTML and do basic CRUD.

Comment: Have you ever had a look at jOOQ: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-jooq this would exactly fit you requirements.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli This looks very promising. I had no idea this existed. I'm going to take a look at this now.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  It seems I have to re-create the structure of my db in order to generate the java code. I made so many changes in mysql workbench, so my schema is drastically different from when I started typing commands. I was hoping for it to just take my schema and generate the class structure but I'll just suck it up and create the class structure.